# How to create a valid file from an object that comes from an api?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following object:

```
const apiObj = {
  "createdAt": 1608202763608,
  "id": "1VdY5QV8ICBpJg1WfpILtRRZCtEF3Q0If",
  "mimeType": "image/jpeg",
  "name": "Screenshot_1.jpg",
  "size": "121560"
}
```

And I want to create a file from this data. The first time I come across this and it seems that some other data is missing, for example, Blob. If so, please tell me what parameters are required to create a file.

I tried to convert apiObj to file using the following script:

```
var convertObjToFile = new File([apiObj], apiObj.name, { type: apiObj.mimeType })
const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer()
dataTransfer.items.add(convertObjToFile)
```

The file is created but it is broken

Comment: Please explain what type of file you want to make ? and there is no data in your obj

Comment: _"it seems that some other data is missing"_ - The actual content of the "file"

Comment: I want to get a file with the same resolution as in my object.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a file with image/jpeg type specified in the apiObj. Because you need the binary content of the file.